# Optimizing sql query: check for all rows in table B if any rows in table C reference the same row in table A

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have 3 tables, A, B and C structured like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    a_id INT REFERENCES a(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE c (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    a_id INT REFERENCES a(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Where the relationships are many-to-one. What i want is, for every row in table b, i want to check if any row in table c has a reference to the same row in table a. Now, I already have the query

```sql
SELECT
    b.id,
    true
FROM
    b
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM c
    WHERE b.a_id = c.a_id
)
UNION
SELECT
    b.id,
    false
FROM
    b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM c
    WHERE b.a_id = c.a_id
)
ORDER BY id
```

Though I am not certain, I think this is doing double work, and going through the table twice, and I am wondering how I could optimize it to only traverse the table once.

Is it possible with a simple query, or do I have to do anything complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the `EXISTS` clause into your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  EXISTS (SELECT null FROM c WHERE c.a_id = b.a_id) AS c_exists
FROM b;
```

The same with an `IN` clause, which I prefer for being even a tad simpler:

```
SELECT
  id,
  a_id IN (SELECT c.a_id FROM c) AS c_exists
FROM b;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a subquery, a left join, and a case.

The subquery gets you a list of distinct `c.a_id` values.

```
             SELECT DISTINCT a_id FROM c;
```

Then do this

```
SELECT b.id, 
       CASE WHEN distinct_ids.a_id IS NULL THEN 'false'
            ELSE 'true' END has_c_row
  FROM b
  LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT a_id FROM c;
       ) distinct_ids ON b.a_id = distinct_ids.a_id
```

This shape of query is called an antijoin or `IS NULL ... LEFT JOIN`. It detects the rows in the first table that don't match rows in the second table.

The subquery gives us a view of the data in table `c` with at most one row per each distinct `a_id` value. Without the subquery, we might get duplicate rows in the result query.

This eliminates your `WHERE EXISTS` [correlated subqueries](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-subqueries.php#MB); even though PostgreSQL's query planner is pretty smart, sometimes it does the slow thing with subqueries like that.

If it is still too slow for you, create these indexes on the a_id columns.

```
ALTER TABLE b ADD INDEX a_id (a_id);
ALTER TABLE c ADD INDEX a_id (a_id);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on this and the other query, and yours is a tiny bit faster

Comment: @Norse: I don't mind that you accept this answer and not mine. Anyway, you shoulnd't be too eager to sqeeze the last part of speed from a query. Do you have performance issues? With these simple queries? You shouldn't. The explain plan may even be different with the next software update or when the data gets smaller or larger. Strive to get your queries as readable as possible. This makes them easier to maintain and usually leads to very good execution plans. Providing appropriate indexes is generally a good idea by the way to speed up read access.

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner. Query plans will vary as tables grow (or shrink). And exact performance changes depending on the server's concurrent workload. In other words **performance is nondeterministic**.  Once you have something decent working, move on. Don't overthink this stuff.

Comment: Yes, I actually chose to use yours instead because of the readability, just forgot to update here. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

i think i understand what you are after

this is how i would do it

```
SELECT b.id, ISNULL(res.result,0) as result
FROM b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.id, 1 as result
    FROM c
    INNER JOIN a on a.id = c.id
) res on b.id = res.id
```

i dont think you need to worry about distinct if they are all unique ids

Comment: it would be interesting to see thgequery execution plan for each answer and see which one is more performant

Comment: I couldn't make yours work, I got the error
`function isnull(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT b.id, ISNULL(res.result,0) as result
                               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`

Comment: Replace `ISNULL` with `COALESCE`. Anyway, I don't think we can assume the a_id to be unique in table c. First of all the shown table structures don't indicate this, and then, if a_id were unique in the table, why make this a separate table at all?

Comment: sorry I realised just now that this is a postgresql question, in MS SQL ISNULL() is a function that replaces nulls with a value, the postgres equivalent as Thorsten mentioned is COALESCE. add DISTINCT in front of the column list and it will ensure uniqueness of results